# BottomSheetDialogFragment not modal

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

Is it possible to make BottomSheetDialogFragment not modal? That means no dimming of underlying content, and not blocking the interaction with it also.

Maybe only via classical fragment?

Answer (score -1):

Try extend `BottomSheetDialogFragment` class by this way

```
public class CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_modal, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
        if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
            ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        }
    }
}
```

From [this](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/03/modal-bottom-sheet-with-material-design.html) article.

Comment: hi, thanks but this seems to doesn't do what i needed

Comment: but it was helpful because it shows how to get behavior programmatically

Comment: @luky Why don't you edit the answer or post a new one that completely addresses your question?